# Phases: How to specify as range endpoint the first non-obsolete predecessor of an obsolete changeset?

Tags: mercurial

Problem:
When using the 'evolve' extension for Mercurial some changesets are marked obsolete and are therefore hidden for example to the 'log' command, like this:

```
$ hg log -11:
abort: hidden revision '-11'!
(use --hidden to access hidden revisions)

$ hg log -12: -T '{rev}'
o 27916
|
| o 27915
| |\
| o | 27914
| | |
| o | 27913
| |/
| | o 27912
| | |
| | o 27911
| | |\
| | o | 27910
| | | |
| | o | 27909
| | | |
| | | | @ 27908
| | | | |
| | | | o 27905
| | | | |
```

Question:
Is there a way to specify a range endpoint to represent either a non-hidden changeset or, if the given changeset is hidden (like '-11'), the preceding non-hidden ancestor (in this example '-12')? I looked at the 'revsets' documentation but failed to find a combination which worked.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question lies in the proper use of revsets. Checkout `hg help revsets` for more indepth information.

In this case this should work:

```
hg glog -r"last(ancestors(-11) and not hidden())::-11" --hidden
```

It will list all changesets from -11 to the first non-hidden ancestor of -11 (including those two).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to use the revsets correctly. For also suppressing the hidden changesets from the final output some ham-fisted shell commands do the trick:


    hg log -r"last(ancestors(-11) and not hidden())::" --hidden -T '{rev} {phase}' | grep -v x  | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\+' | tr '\n' " " | sed 's/ [[:digit:]]/ or&/g' | xargs -I _ hg log -r "_"

Comment: why throw shell at it and not use revsets for that, too? In this case it probably suffices to simply omit the --hidden keyword to log

Comment: so you want basically only one revision? Then try `-r"last(not hidden() and ancestors(-11))". Really do make use of revlogs :) It's more powerful than bash postprocessing ever can be.

Comment: No, I want a range, from e.g. '-11:' with '-11' automatically replaced by the last preceding non-hidden changeset if necessary.

Comment: well, just add a : to the last revset I gave: `-r"last(not hidden() and ancestors(-11)):"